# get random ephemeral external IP address in my google cloud compute instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Every time I destroy my compute instance and create new one, the same ephemeral external IP address is assigned. I haven't used static ip. But always same set of ip addresses is being assigned. How do I get completely random external ip on my instances?

P.S. I use default network interface which is already there in the cloud console.

Answer (score 1):

If an instance is stopped, any ephemeral external IP addresses assigned to the instance are released back into the general Compute Engine pool and become available for use by other projects. When a stopped instance is started again, a new ephemeral external IP address is assigned to the instance. There is no guarantee that you will get a specific IP every time or will get completely different IP address always. You may get the same IP or even could get a completely new IP from the pool. You can find detail at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#externaladdresses).

If your use case is to assign multiple external IP addresses to a single instance, you can set up multiple forwarding rules to point to a single target instance using [protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding).

Comment: I created one instance got an ip address, after completing my work i deleted it created new one got he same ip and so on and on for 4/5 times. That doesn't look like total random to me. 
Will this depend on network interface that I create?

Comment: Assigning external ephemeral IP to a new GCE instance is completely random and in your case, you got the same IP luckily. Also, it does not depend on the network interface. What is your use case?

Comment: Maybe because they have dome kind of cache database so if you create a new instance it will use this same ip from the cache